# Angular 9. ngx-datatable delay on row expanding

Tags: angular, client-side, ngx-datatable, treetable

I'm using ngx-datatable client side tree table.
When i'm expanding row with lots of children rows i have huge delay between click and moment when all children rendered. Is it possible to avoid this delay? [demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XoTm.gif)

Comment: Are you using in-memory data for table population?

Comment: How many records are there  in the expanded row?

Comment: @RafaqatAli Yes. This is mock data, so there is no asynchronous requests

Comment: @BrunoFarias it's about 100 records.